# AWS Javascript SDK V3 with Typescript

Tags: aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

Has anyone used AWS javascript sdk v3 with typescript. I am trying to figure out how to use types in my lambda function. For example in this code snippet what should I use for the return type and how do I get/import type declations? Thank you

```
getAllIamUsers(): ?? {
        
        const input = {
            MaxItems: 100,
            Marker: null
        };     
        
       const command = new ListUsersCommand(input);
       const usersResponse = await client.send(command); 
       return usersResponse.Users;       

    }
```

Comment: The documentation where you got those classes should also be able to tell the return types. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1):

For correct Lambda handler types you have to use the [aws-lambda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda) package that provides the `Handler` type:

```
import { Handler } from 'aws-lambda';
import { IAMClient, ListUsersRequest, ListUsersCommand, ListUsersCommandOutput } from '@aws-sdk/client-iam';

export const getAllIamUsers: Handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    const input: ListUsersRequest = {
        MaxItems: 100,
        Marker: undefined
    };

    const command = new ListUsersCommand(input);
    const usersResponse = await client.send(command);
    return usersResponse.Users;
}
```

Optionally, you could specify the event and result type via generica `Handler<Event, Result>`.